# How to use INSERT OR IGNORE in SQL

Tags: sqlite, machine-learning

I want to get input data from a machine learning model and then prediction to insert in a sql database. I also want to avoid saving already saved input and prediction data.

```
`for i in range(5):
    
    if models.predict([data["Complaint1"][i]])=="STUDENTS":
        new_data=pd.concat([
                    pd.DataFrame(vectoriserst.transform([data['Complaint1'][i]]).toarray(), columns=vectoriserst.get_feature_names()),
                    pd.DataFrame(vectoriserst.transform([data['complaint2'][i]]).toarray(), columns=vectoriserst.get_feature_names())
                  ], axis=1
                   
                  )
        Predictions=modelst.predict(new_data) 
     else :
         new_data=pd.concat([
                    pd.DataFrame(vectoriserfc.transform([data['Complaint1'][i]]).toarray(), columns=vectoriserfc.get_feature_names()),
                    pd.DataFrame(vectoriserfc.transform([data['complaint2'][i]]).toarray(), columns=vectoriserfc.get_feature_names())
                  ], axis=1
                   
                  )
        Predictions=modelfc.predict(new_data)

    conn=sqlite3.connect("mydata.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
    """
   CREATE TABLE Table ( id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                 FolderNumber TEXT,
                                 Complaint1 TEXT,
                                 Complaint2 TEXT,
                                 Prediction)
   """
   )
 

      cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Table (FolderNumber, Complaint1, Complaint2, Prediction ) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" %(data['FolderNumber'][i], data['Complaint1'][i], data['Complaint2'][i], Prediction))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IGNORE will only IGNORE constraint conflicts for UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY/CHECK/NOT NULL conflicts.

The only column that has such a constraint, in the table you create, is the id column. As you are not providing a value, then due to it being an alias of the  rowid, instead of null the value will be generated (1 then likely 2 then likely 3 ....) and will be a UNIQUE value.

As such you will never get a conflict and thus no insert is ignored.

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

> I also want to avoid saving already saved input and prediction data.

Then you very likely want a UNIQUE constraint if the "already saved input" can be determined by a single column. If the "already saved input" equates to multiple columns then you would need to either make those columns the PRIMARY KEY or have an UNIQUE INDEX over those  columns.

Perhaps consider the following, based upon the SQL within your code. It consists of three examples.

The first example is based upon your table definition and allows the replicated data to be inserted as previously explained.

The second example empties the table and then adds a UNIQUE index. This time only 1 row is inserted the other rows are ignored.

The third example creates the table, after dropping it, and adds the UNIQUE constraint to the prediction column.

The SQL is:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
/* EXAMPLE 1 - original */
CREATE TABLE `Table` ( id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    FolderNumber TEXT,
    Complaint1 TEXT,
    Complaint2 TEXT,
    Prediction
)
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `Table` (FolderNumber, Complaint1, Complaint2, Prediction ) 
    VALUES
        ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
;

/* EXAMPLE 2 UNIQUE INDEX */
DELETE FROM `table`;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS uidx_table_prediction ON `table` (prediction);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `Table` (FolderNumber, Complaint1, Complaint2, Prediction ) 
    VALUES
        ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
;

/* EXAMPLE 3 UNIQUE column constraint */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
CREATE TABLE `Table` ( id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    FolderNumber TEXT,
    Complaint1 TEXT,
    Complaint2 TEXT,
    Prediction UNIQUE
)
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `Table` (FolderNumber, Complaint1, Complaint2, Prediction ) 
    VALUES
        ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
```

The Output, from the SQLite Tool (Navicate for SQLite), is :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`
> OK
> Time: 0.117s


CREATE TABLE `Table` ( id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    FolderNumber TEXT,
    Complaint1 TEXT,
    Complaint2 TEXT,
    Prediction
)
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `Table` (FolderNumber, Complaint1, Complaint2, Prediction ) 
    VALUES
        ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.024s


DELETE FROM `table`
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.024s


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS uidx_table_prediction ON `table` (prediction)
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `Table` (FolderNumber, Complaint1, Complaint2, Prediction ) 
    VALUES
        ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.024s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


CREATE TABLE `Table` ( id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    FolderNumber TEXT,
    Complaint1 TEXT,
    Complaint2 TEXT,
    Prediction UNIQUE
)
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `Table` (FolderNumber, Complaint1, Complaint2, Prediction ) 
    VALUES
        ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.024s
```

i.e. the affected rows (inserted rows) is 1 for the latter 2 examples but 3 for the first.